# Multi-Level Nesting using dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

How can you use multi-level nesting, like this example in d3, using dc.js?

```
var expensesTotalByDay = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .key(function(d) { return d.date; })
  .rollup(function(v) { return d3.sum(v, function(d) { return d.amount; }); })
  .map(expenses);
console.log(JSON.stringify(expensesTotalByDay));
```

I know that dc.js uses d3, but I don't get how to use it.
Is there an example/tutorial available?

Comment: where are you using `dc.js`

Comment: Here are example (http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/raw/3176159/) first result on google..

Comment: dc.js is all about the crossfilter integration, so I'd look at how to aggregate using that rather than nesting - this will allow it to respond to filtering in other charts.

Comment: Also the [wiki](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki#community-examples) links to many examples and tutorials.